# How are classes not objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I was reading "[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)", (specifically the chapter about the prototype design pattern) and it stated that...

> "Prototype is particularly useful with **static languages like C++ where classes are not objects**, and little or no type information is available at run-time." (pg 121)

*(emphasis mine)*

I had always thought that classes were synonymous to objects, and I'm confused as to what this statement means.  How are classes not objects, and why does it matter if a language is static?

Comment: Objects are *instances* of classes.

Comment: The best counterargument would be the `typeid` operator. A class (or other type) may not "is-a" object, but it certainly "has-a" object. Anyway, introspective capability is very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, this declares a class:

```
class A {
public:
  int a;
};
```

whereas this declares an object:

```
A a;
```

One cannot interrogate a class a run-time, as one can interrogate an object. It makes sense to say, "object 'a', what is your address? Please invoke `operator+`. etc." In C++, with its static typing, it makes no sense to say, "Class A, what is your list of members? Please add a new member, "b"."

In other languages (Python comes to mind), one can manipulate classes in this way, because each class is also an object. In addition to serving as a template for objects, the class *itself* is an object -- it can be printed, modified, etc.

Answer (score 5):

A class in C++ is not an object: a class is a description of how to build an object, and a reference to a type of an object.

Compare with a language like Python: in python, like in C++, you instantiate an object from a class.  Unlike C++, the class you used is also an object: it usually has type `type`, and you can create new ones at runtime, manipulate them like any other object, or even create objects which are classes which themselves have different types.

You may be wondering why you'd want this, and usually you don't need it -- it's like C++ template meta-programming, you only need it when you *need* it because you can't achieve your goal in any other way.  It's probably also the case that problems you'd solve in Python with meta-classes you'd solve in C++ using template meta-programming.

Answer (score 3):

For example, a class could describe what a book is: Name, Author, Date of Publishing, Description.

An object of the "Book" class would be a specific book: C++ Primer Plus, Stephen Prata, 2005, A book that teaches C++.

So, classes are not the same as objects.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Andrew Aylett said.

> A class in C++ is not an object: a class is a description of how to build an object, and a reference to a type of an object.

Furthermore, in languages like Python or smalltalk.  Everything is an object.  A function is a object, a class is a object.  As such these languages are Dynamically Typed, meaning that types are checked during runtime and variables can take on any type.

C++ is statically typed. Variables can only take on one type, and type checking is performed at compile time.

So in python for instance, you can modify a class on the fly. Add functions and fields, because it is an object, and can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

What that sentence refers is to is the fact that classes are not first-order entities in a language like C++. In other languages, you can pass a class as a parameter to a function, e.g., the same way as you can pass an object or a function as a parameter.

There are many more implications of being classes first-order entities or not, e.g., the possibility of modifying a class at runtime, or inspecting the full internals of a class, etc.

Usually classes are found to be first-order entities in dynamic languages like ruby, or in the meta object protocol for lisp, etc.

Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When a class is said to be an object, it means that there's an object that represents that class at runtime. In C++, classes are dissolved at compile time. Their instances (i.e. objects) are merely sequences of bytes holding the object's fields, without any reference to the class itself. Now, C++ does provide some type information at runtime via RTTI, but that's only for polymorphic types, and is not considered a class object.

The lack of having objects that represent classes at runtime is the reason there's no reflection in C++ - there's just no way to get information about a certain class, as there's no object that represent it.

BTW, C++ is considered a 2-level language: objects are instances of classes, but classes are not instances of anything, because they only exist at compile type. On 3-level languages such as C# and Java, classes are also objects at runtime, and as such, are themselves instances of yet another class (Class in Java, Type in C#). The last class is an instance of itself, hence the language only has 3 levels. There are languages with more levels, but that's beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: "RTTI" is not an official term. Any sort of type query applied to (an object of) non-polymorphic type, such as `typeid(3)`, is still valid, but it is not "RTTI" in common parlance because it doesn't require certain ABI features that may be turned off by the switch named `--no-rtti` or whatever platform-specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are not the same as Objects. A class is (more or less) the type, and an Object is the instance, simmiliar to the following:

```
int i;
YourClass object;
```

Here you wouldn't say `i` and `int` are the same -- neither are `YourClass` and `object`.

What the statement wants to say: Many object orientated languages are *very* object orientated, so that they start making everything (or nearly everything) an object (of one or another class). So in many languages a `class` would be an instance (hence an object) of some `class class` (which can be confusing).

This sometimes has advantages, as you can treat classes (that's types) in such languages like you could treat any other object. You can than do very dynamic stuff with them, like store them in variables or even manipulate the classes during runtime (e.g. to create new classes your program finds the need to have).

Take a look at this c++-similiar pseudo code:

```
YourClass myObject = new YourClass();                // creates an object (an instance)
Class baseClass = myObject.get_class();              // store the class of myObject in baseClass. That's storing a type in a variable (more or less)
Class subClass = myObject.inherit();                 // dynamically create a new class, that only exists in variable subClass (a Class-object), inheriting from baseClass
subClass.add_method(some_function);                  // extend the new class by adding a new method
subClass.get_class() subClass.create_instance();     // declare a new variable (object) of your newly created type 
BaseClass another_onne = subClass.create_instance(); // also valid, since you inherited
```

This obviously doesn't translate well to c++, because of c++'s strict typing. Other languages are more dynamic in typing, and there this flexibility can come in handy (and make thinks more complicated; sometimes both at the same time). Still I think it explains the principle, if you understand c++.

Answer (score 1):

> I had always thought that classes were synonymous to objects

The language in OOP literature is sometimes not specific. It doesn't help either that programming languages have somewhat different notions of what an object is.

A class is a template or definition from where objects (instances of that class) are created. That is, a class provides the structure, type signatures and behaviors that objects of that class (or type... more on that later.)

An object is just a location in memory of an instance of that class.

Wikipedia provides good documentation on this. I suggest you read it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(object-oriented_programming)

Also, there is the concept of a *type*. A type (or interface as sometimes called in some literature or programming languages) is typically the collection of type/method signatures (and possibly behavior). Things like Java interfaces and C++ pure virtual classes tend to represent *types* (but aren't exactly the same).

Then a class that conforms to that *type* (be it interface or pure virtual class) is an *implementation* of that *type*.

That class, that *type implementation* is just a recipe of how to construct objects of that class/type in memory.

When you instantiate a class/type, you reify, construct an instance (object) of that class in memory.

In C++, a class is not an object since a class itself is not instantiated. A C++ class is not an instance of some other class (see the definitions I put above.)

OTH, in languages like Java, a class itself is represented by instances of a primordial class (java.lang.Class). So a class X has an object in memory (an java.lang.Class instance) associated with it. And with it, with that *"class"* object, you can (in theory) instantiate or manufacture another instance (or object) of class/type X.

It can get confusing. I strongly suggest you search and read the literature on classes, types, prototypes and objects/instances.

> and I'm confused as to what this statement means. How are classes not
>   objects,

As explained above. A class is not an object. An object is an instance, a piece of memory constructed and initialized by the "recipe" of a class or type.

> and why does it matter if a language is static?

That part of the book is a bit misleading because Java, for example, is statically typed and yet, classes can be object themselves. Perhaps the text is refering to dynamically typed languages (like JavaScript) where classes can also be objects or instances.

My suggestion is to never use the word object, and to simply limit the vocabulary to "classes" and "instances". But that's my personal predilection. Other people might disagree, and so be it.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler I can put it for you to understand it:

An object is a "physical" instance of a class. It consumes memory while the program is running.

A class describes an object: Hierarchy, properties, methods. A class it's like a "template" for creating objects.